# Pivot dataframe without lose repeated values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, dataset

I have this entry

```
id   value  reps
1    333    1
1    332    4
1    335    1   
4    555    3
4    225    1
444  2      5
```

I want this, organizing the values by the column reps from less to more

```
id   col1 col2 col3 col4 
1    333  335  332  nan 
4    225  555  nan  nan 
444  2    nan  nan  nan
```

I have tried to use pivot table and got this

```
dataframe = dataframe.pivot_table(index='id', columns='reps', values='value')
dataframe = dataframe.rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()

id   1      3      4    5
1    334    nan    332  nan
4    225.5  555.5  nan  nan
444  nan    nan    nan  2
```

Comment: Do  you have any reason to believe that the pair (id, reps) will be different in every row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group by "id" and create ("value", "reps") tuples, and sort it by "reps":

```py
df_grouped = df.groupby("id")[["value", "reps"]].apply(lambda x: sorted(list(zip(x.value, x.reps)), key=lambda x: x[1]))

[Out]:
id
1      [(333, 1), (335, 1), (332, 4)]
4                [(225, 1), (555, 3)]
444                          [(2, 5)]
```

Create result dataframe from above sorted tuples using "value" as data (which is at index `0`).

```py
df_result = pd.DataFrame(data=[[y[0] for y in x] for x in df_grouped], index=df_grouped.index)

[Out]:
       0      1      2
id                    
1    333    335    332
4    225    555    NaN
444    2    NaN    NaN
```

`pandas` fills in default column names starting with `0`. You can change it if required:

```py
df_result.columns = list(range(1, len(df_result.columns) + 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can first sort the dataframe by `reps` (and also by `id` if it's the case) and then change `reps` by the cumulative count for each `id`.

Then you can perform the pivot table as you suggested.

```
df \
  .sort_values(['id','reps']) \
  .pipe(lambda df_: df_.assign(reps=df_.groupby(['id']).cumcount()+1)) \
  .pivot_table(index='id', columns='reps', values='value') \
  .add_prefix('col')
```

It will not return col4 with `NaN` in your expected output, but you can add it later.

Comment: Correct approach, you don't need the `pipe`, you can use a callable in `assign` (`.assign(reps=lambda d: d.groupby('id').cumcount().add(1))`).